# Bouncing ball geometric sequence question

Tags: sequences-and-series

**When a ball falls vertically off a table, it rebounds 75% of its height after each bounce. If it travels a total distance of 490 cm, how high was the table top above the floor?**

The trouble I am having is that the ball will never actually stop bouncing because it keeps re
bouncing 75% of the previous height each time. So how will I solve this?

Comment: Are you familiar with summing a geometric progression?

Comment: But each bounce takes only $75\%$ of the time the previous took, so the ball will come to rest in finite time (after infinitely many bounces).

Comment: Can you solve this for me and then I can understand better.

Comment: Let the height of the table be $h$. How far does the ball travel until it hits the floor for the first, second, third time?

Answer (score 5):

Here is a method which avoids summing a geometric progression (at least it hides a method for computing the sum).

Call the height of the table $h=4a$ and the total distance travelled $d$. To the top of the first bounce the ball travels down $4a$ and back up $3a$. The remainder of the track of the ball is exactly as if it had fallen off a table of height $3a$ - and simply by scaling we see that this would be $\frac 34d$. So we have $7a+\frac34d=d$ and it is easy to solve from there.

Comment: (+1) I would like to add that what is hidden here is the assumption (which is a fact) that the total distance travelled is proportional to the initial height. Although I do not know how else to justify this formally if not by summation, it seems intuitive enough to assume. (But for logical completeness, I have not seen a way to avoid an infinite sum or a limiting argument.)

Comment: @Tunococ Compare the first bounce from $4a$ with the first bounce from $3a$, the second bounces, the third bounces etc - the factor is $\frac 34$ all the way along. This is equivalent to a method often used to prove the formula for the sum of a geometric series $rS=r+r^2+r^3+\dots=S-1$

Comment: Exactly. That is why I said infinite sums are still needed. You just hid them, as you stated :)

Comment: Thx for the great answer. But I don't understand what you mean when you say `simply by scaling we see that this would be (3/4)d`. Could you elaborate on that more. Thx very much.

Comment: @AnkurSharma - see my previous comment - starting from $3a$ compared with starting from $4a$, the first bounce is three-quarters as high, so is the second bounce etc. Note that using this to compute the total distance travelled assumes that the distance is well-defined - if it were infinite, for example, we'd be subtracting two infinities, which is not a well-defined operation.

Answer (score 1):

Let $h_n$ be the height of the ball after the $n$-th bounce, and $h>0$ the height of the table. Then we have
$$
h_0=h,\ h_n=\frac34 h_{n-1} \quad \forall n \ge 1,
$$
i.e.
$$
h_n=\left(\frac34\right)^nh_0=\left(\frac34\right)^nh.
$$
The total distance that the ball travels after its fall is
$$
d=h_0+2\sum_{n=1}^\infty h_n=\left[-1+2\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac34\right)^n\right]h=\left(-1+\frac{2}{1-\frac34}\right)h=7h.
$$
Thus
$$
h=\frac17d=70 \text{ cm }.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Using $S= a/(1-r)$ and allowing $x$ to be the original height you have the following equation. (Note:  the original drop is only added to the series because it is the drop distance.)

$$ x+\frac{ 2x(.75)}{ 1- .75 }=490$$

We double the $x$ in the numerator which is equal to (a) because after the original drop the ball goes up then comes back down, this makes us double the distance.

Solving we get: $x+6x=490$
 $$7x=490$$
Answer:             x=70cm